# Alert from HTML script in Django

Tags: javascript, django, html, alert

I am prying to display **alert** in my **Django** project.

I am passing values from **views.py** to **singup.html** to display alert based on condition.
But initially my alert variable in HTML doesn't get value.
Only after clicking on Submit button alert is initialized and displays the required alert.

Views.py

```
def signup(request):
    d = {}
    data={}

    template={}
    context={}
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm1(request.POST)
        print("hello212")
        if request.POST.get('email1') and request.POST.get('password1'):
            post = Register1()
            post.email = request.POST.get('email1')
            post.password = request.POST.get('password1')
            post.repeatpassword=request.POST.get('repeatpassword1')
            print(post.email)
            print(post.password)
            print(post.repeatpassword)
            data=Register.objects.filter(email__iexact=post.email).exists()
            print (data)
            if post.password == post.repeatpassword:
                if data == False:
                    post.save()
                    alert = 0
                    print("check")
                else:
                    alert = 2
            context={
                "alert":alert,
            }
            print (context)
            # template= "personal_anshul/signup.html"
    return render(request, "personal_anshul/signup.html", context)
```

Signup:

```
<input type="hidden" name="alert" value="{{alert}}" readonly>
<script>
    function check() {
    <!--{% for message in messages %}-->
    <!--<div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>-->
    <!--{% endfor %}-->
    <!--alert("check")-->
    console.log({{ alert }})

    if ({{alert}} == 2)
    {
        alert("id exists")
    }
    else{
        alert("You Genius!")
        }


}
</script>
```

Alert value when i go to my page for the first time:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6su6R.png)

Alert value after i click on submit button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylcww.png)

How to initialize alert so that i get a value to compare my condition when i visit my page first time? Currently alert gets value after clicking on submit button.

Comment: ajax is the term you are looking for. when the user enters his/her mail, you should do an ajax call to check if the mail is already used and return true or false... You can directly (while the user is typing/after filling the form) send the alert.

Answer (score 0):

def signup(request):
    d = {}
    data={}

```
template={}
context={}
alert = 0
print(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm1(request.POST)
    print("hello212")
    if request.POST.get('email1') and request.POST.get('password1'):
        post = Register1()
        post.email = request.POST.get('email1')
        post.password = request.POST.get('password1')
        post.repeatpassword=request.POST.get('repeatpassword1')
        print(post.email)
        print(post.password)
        print(post.repeatpassword)
        data=Register.objects.filter(email__iexact=post.email).exists()
        print (data)
        if post.password == post.repeatpassword:
            if data == False:
                post.save()
                alert = 0
                print("check")
            else:
                alert = 2

        # template= "personal_anshul/signup.html"
context={
    "alert":alert,
}
#print (context)
return render(request, "personal_anshul/signup.html", context)
```